# How to Redirect from Subdirectory to Direct Url? via .Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

Here is my question:

I want to 301 redirect from:

> domain.com/blog/how-to-stuffs/

to:

> domain.com/how-to-stuffs/

Please share the .htaccess code, to perform such kind of redirect thank you.

Comment: `Redirect 301 /blog/ https://example.com/` should redirect all URLs from `/blog/.*` .

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Redirect "/blog/how-to-stuffs/" "/how-to-stuffs/"
```

Or, only use this if the above doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/blog\/how-to-stuffs\/?$
RewriteRule ^ /how-to-stuffs/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I want to do the same with tons of URLs actually, like all URLs in the site, so I have do it manually for each URL? please help.

Comment: @RaviSharma, if you want to do for all urls in site, you can do it in one go. If you want to do it with tons of URLs, you should either manually include all of them, or exclude the ones which you do not want to redirect